# How to use Dropzone 5.7.0 in IE 11

Tags: dropzone.js

since Dropzone 5.7.0, dropzone.js is not working in Internet Explorer 11. I know it is outdated browser, but our application with dropzone implementation works fine on IE11, but Dropzone drop support of IE11 for our application now.

The bug occured when page opened (no dropzone init etc., only dropzone.js include).

SCRIPT5009: Object Symbol is not defined.
dropzone.js (3196,11)

Dropzone 5.5.0 works fine on IE11.

Any idea please?

Comment: Related to these issues?  
https://gitlab.com/meno/dropzone/-/issues/225  
https://gitlab.com/meno/dropzone/-/issues/53

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue by adding following script tag.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.8.7/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

Dropzone.js had arrow functions and lot of other things which are not supported in IE11. Therefore, it converted from es6 to es5 using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

After researching a bit found that it needed polyfill support and hence script.

Comment: Latest https://unpkg.com/core-js-bundle@3.8.3/minified.js fixes that as well.

Comment: Though @poojakapuriya's answer works. for some cases, as in for using dropzone which has Symbol iterators. using slava's answer worked for me